# All the AndroidX versions different from the compile

Tags: flutter

I've migrated my project to AndroidX cause i was having some errors, but now i'm receiving a loop of errors that the androidX class has a different version from the compile:

```
Android dependency 'androidx.fragment:fragment' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.1.0-alpha04) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

And it's always a different a class, i've already tried implementing this code but every time i add a line it gives me other class different from the compile:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.fragment:fragment:v4:1.1.0-alpha04'
    }
}
```

Comment: I just had the same problem in my project. Solved by checking dependency graph via `./gradlew app:dependencies` to see which dependencies have the same dependency on different versions. In my case, it was Google services and Room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my error migrating my project to androidX in gradle.properties, and by Refactor => Migrate to AndroidX, and adding this code to my app/build.gradle:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}
```

Answer (score 25):

I've had similar issue, just solved it using this inside app/build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core') {
                details.useVersion "1.0.1"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.lifecycle') {
                details.useVersion "2.0.0"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.versionedparcelable') {
                details.useVersion "1.0.0"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.fragment') {
                details.useVersion "1.0.0"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.appcompat') {
                details.useVersion "1.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In case if anyone has a problem adding the above mentioned configutation into build.gradle file here is a gist https://gist.github.com/valekar/3e96d939af00c569fa1eec58b8082289

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I also added `android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.debug.obsoleteApi=true` in the `gradle.properties` file

Comment: excellent, best answer out there for me, thanks!

Answer (score 22):

If the problem persists, you might want to upgrade the gradle version in **android/build.grandle**

Change:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

To:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'//latest version
}
```

You should also update your Kotlin version.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted this.../android/build.gradle (not .../android/app/build.grade) and that made the problem out:

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core' &&
           !details.requested.name.contains('androidx')) {
        details.useVersion "1.0.1"
            }
    }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing my com.android.tools.build:gradle to version 3.3.1 fixed the issue for me