# I'm trying to use cloud firestore with flutter but i'm getting errors

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is the version I'm using:

**cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10+2**

This is the error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
>   Android dependency 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.0) classpath.
>   You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

If you need more details just tell me what you need.

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve the error?  The error message seems pretty clear, it looks like you have a versioning mismatch in your dependencies. Have you resolved that yet? The question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872814/all-the-androidx-versions-different-from-the-compile) seems very similar to your own.

Comment: I didn't try anything I don't know how to fix it