# Image_picker dependency in Flutter doesn't let me compile my app with an Error message

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, dart

I wanted to add the image_picker library for my App registration, where the user can pick an image when he clicks on a button. My dependecies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^3.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.2
  password_strength: ^0.1.2
  keyboard_avoider: ^0.1.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.2+3
```

Everything worked nice but after adding the image_picker in the pubspec.yaml i get the error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Android dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime' has different version for the compile (2.0.0-rc01) and runtime (2.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin firebase_auth...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'firebase_auth'.

  > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
The plugin firebase_auth could not be built due to the issue above.
Exited (sigterm)

Edit:
Flutter doctor -v Output

```
PS D:\Flutter Projekte\helper> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.535], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (6 days ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Ozan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.2
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[√] VS Code (version 1.41.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Ozan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

flutter doctor -- android-licenses output

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
Warning: Observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Ozan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\.temp\PackageOperation01' (Expected 'C:\Users\Ozan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager')
Warning: Observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Ozan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\.temp\PackageOperation01' (Expected 'C:\Users\Ozan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager')
                                                                                Warning: File C:\Users\Ozan\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
```

local.properties file

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\Ozan\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\src\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: Edited in my post

Comment: Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: Does it work now? If not, set the system variable `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk`, restart your IDE, then try again.

Comment: I set the variable but after restart still the same message.

Comment: You are using AndroidX in your project correct? You can check here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration#how-do-i-know-if-my-project-is-using-androidx

Comment: Yes, i use AndroidX in my project. properties file looks same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update flutter to version 1.12 which uses AndroidX by default:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-1.12.13#android

You can upgrade by executing the following command:

```
 flutter upgrade
```

After doing flutter upgrade, then add the sdk path to android_home:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="YOUR_SDK_PATH"
```

Also upgrade both the android gradle in the `build.gradle` and the kotlin version:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' 
}
```

Comment: what is the problem, in your question their is more than one error

Comment: All the errors come when i add the image_picker dependency. I need it for my registration so a user can pick a profile picture. But after adding the depedency in my pubspec.yaml the app doesnt start and give the errors in my post

Comment: But its interesting for my why it doesnt work and how to fix such problems :)

Comment: can you check ur local.properties file?

Comment: Edited in the post

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872814/all-the-androidx-versions-different-from-the-compile

Comment: is the error this `SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable` or this `Android dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime' has different version for the compile (2.0.0-rc01) and runtime (2.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution`?

Comment: do flutter clean and remove firebase auth just for testing

Comment: this might be from firebase auth remove it and do flutter clean

Comment: I removed firebase_auth + clean   and i get the error "SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.".

Comment: is the sdk located here sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\Ozan\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk

Comment: My sdk is in C:\Users\Ozan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: The imager picker works now after editing the sdk path variable to ANDROID_HOME and the given sdk path. But when i add the firebase_auth i get again errors

Comment: I fixxed it, after searching google and trying every soluition it worked. In the end i updated gradle version and kotlin version

Comment: So same as the link I shared in the comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872814/all-the-androidx-versions-different-from-the-compile

Comment: Please upgrade your image_picker dependencies to latest one. It will resolve problem.